# How to decode non-b-prefixed string like '\xd0\xbc' stored in variable in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I have some variable from API.
For example:

```
a == '\xd0\xbc'
```

I need to get variable b by decoding a:

```
b == 'М'
```

But I can't write in code something like this:

```
a = b'\xd0\xbc'
b = a.decode()
```

because this text (\xd0\xbc) is already in the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `str.encode()` and pass `encoding="latin"` to get `b == 'M'`.

```
a = str.encode('\xd0\xbc', 'latin')
b = a.decode()
print(b)
```

If `"latin"` is not the standard encodings you were looking for, [try others](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

Comment: I cannot imagine a different encoding than Latin1 here, because it has *by definition* the unicode value for all unicode code points below 256.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Although, using `"utf-8"` would have given a different result.

Answer (score 0):

will this help ? I would guess there is a better way however I do not know it

```
>>> a = r'\xd0\xbc'
>>> b = 'b"{}"'.format(a)
>>> c = eval(b)
>>> d = c.decode()
>>> d
'\u043c'
```